# Tried proxying com.w.monitoring.headlessclient.utils.Logger to support a circular dependency, but it is not an interface

Tags: java, logging, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, guice

This is my main class:

```
static Logger logger;
static StringUtils stringUtils;

//java -cp ... <VM argument> main.class.Name <program arguments>
public static void main(String... args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    logger = InjectorSingleton.getInstance().guiceInjector.getInstance(Logger.class);
    stringUtils = InjectorSingleton.getInstance().guiceInjector.getInstance(StringUtils.class);
}
```

This is my Module class:

```
public class AppInjector extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Logger.class);
    }
}
```

My Logger class is:

```
public class Logger {

    private StringUtils stringUtils;
    public boolean isDebug;

    @Singleton
    @Inject
    public Logger(StringUtils stringUtils) {
        this.stringUtils =  stringUtils;
        setIsVerbose();
    }


public class StringUtils {

    Logger logger;

    @Singleton
    @Inject
    public StringUtils(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
```

I run the main class and get this exception:

```
1) Tried proxying com.w.monitoring.headlessclient.utils.Logger to support a circular dependency, but it is not an interface.
  while locating com.w.monitoring.headlessclient.utils.Logger
    for parameter 0 at com.w.monitoring.headlessclient.utils.StringUtils.<init>(StringUtils.java:21)
  while locating com.w.monitoring.headlessclient.utils.StringUtils
    for parameter 0 at com.w.monitoring.headlessclient.utils.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:14)
  while locating com.w.monitoring.headlessclient.utils.Logger

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:1014)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1040)
```

I changed the config to:

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(Logger.class).toInstance(new Logger());
}
```

but how should I init the specific instance (missing args to the ctor)

What should I fix in the guice config method?

Comment: You can fix the circular dependency by switching from constructor injection to field or method injection on one of the classes.  But ideally you'd remove the circular dependency entirely.

Comment: anyhow, I can use un-targeted binding?  if not how can I bind ti instance properly? who init the Logger's ctor params?